# Who is responsible for cleaning up an [in] VARIANT parameter?

Tags: com, ole, ole-automation

In an interface that has an `[in] VARIANT param`, does the caller own the VARIANT that is copied to it? Should the callee call `VariantClear` (or ATL `CComVariant::Attach`) on the value to ensure that it is cleaned up? Is there anywhere the Automation memory management rules are documented (to add to [COM memory management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))?

I know that an `[in] VARIANT *param` is a pointer owned by the caller, but an `[in] VARIANT param` is a struct that is copied to the callee so it is kind of weird. If ownership is not transferred, then why would anyone even define an interface using `[in] VARIANT param`? In stdcall x86 and x86_64 calling convention it never fits in registers so it is not more efficient than `[in] VARIANT *param`, so it seems kind of pointless.

I am asking because I am wondering how to implement [IUIAutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler::HandlePropertyChangedEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee696120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes, `[in]` parameters are owned by the caller, whether of type `VARIANT` or otherwise. What additional clarification do you need? I'm not sure why you feel `[in] VARIANT` is fundamentally different from, say, `[in] IUnknown*` There, the COM interface pointer is also copied - would you argue that this must imply the ownership of it is transferred?

Comment: I guess I was wary b/c 1) I don’t know all of Automation’s exceptions to [COM memory rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (e.g. SysFreeString instead of CoTaskMemFree), 2) I don’t know why someone would use `[in] VARIANT` vs `[in] VARIANT *`, 3) It would be far simpler if every VARIANT had to be VariantClear’d before it goes out of scope. But if you shallow copy a VARIANT, now you have to worry about a VARIANT that owns its data vs a VARIANT that doesn’t own its data, and 4) this is the first time I’ve seen a pass-by-value struct in COM.

Comment: If you pass a variant by value and what you pass in the variant can fit in it (integers, floats, dates, etc.), then you don't need any extra allocation/free on the heap (all happens on stack - at least when running client & server inproc). I guess it's a design choice. There are tons of interface defined like this in the SDK (mshtml.h/IE for example).

Comment: Re: `SysFreeString` instead of `CoTaskMemFree` - so are you equally worried about `[in] BSTR` parameters, claiming it would be much simpler if every `BSTR` pointer hat to be `SysFreeString`ed before it goes out of scope, or wondering why interfaces don't use `[in] BSTR*` instead? Do you have difficulty separating `BSTR` pointers that own their data from those that don't own their data when they are shallow-copied? Think of `VARIANT` as a fundamental type in Automation, similar to `BSTR` or `IUnknown*`. The fact that the C keyword `struct` happens to be used in its definition is irrelevant.

Comment: Note that memory handling COM exceptions have no influence on the general rules for managing the lifetime of an object.  So, although I agree it's not particularly nice to have to know about `IUnknown::Release`, `CoTaskMemFree`, `VariantClear` and `SysFreeString`, they are applied in mostly the same way, and never on an `[in]` argument (well, except if you `IUnknown::AddRef`ed an `[in]` interface pointer, you should release it when you no longer need it).

Comment: So, since `[in]` arguments must be kept alive for the duration of the call, the callee has no business in freeing them.  The caller may even reuse the same values for subsequent, unrelated calls.  Note also that plain `[in] VARIANT` arguments are probably more common than `[in] VARIANT *` arguments.